# Build a dropdown from values of a database field

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a field in the database that get populated from a textarea. I insert a lot of values and separate those by inserting a new line for each value. How can i build a dropdown menu from this field in rails?

This is actually what is in the database field

```
["Drop\r\nDown\r\ntext\r\ntext\r\ntext"]
```

Comment: you should go accept answers you have made in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 > "Drop\r\nDown\r\ntext\r\ntext\r\ntext".split("\r\n")
 => ["Drop", "Down", "text", "text", "text"]
```

Comment: Yeah thats what i did, forgot to check the console and all i was doing  is split("\n"). Didint see the r. Thank you anyway.